# core nlp truecaseannotator not found

Tags: stanford-nlp

I just got started with CoreNLP version 3.6.0. I've downloaded this version from [this website](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2015-12-09.zip). Using the commandline pipeline, I've been able to perform the standard pipeline annotators but ran into a problem with the truecase annotator:

Here's a copy of the terminal output:

> loadClassifier=edu/stanford/nlp/models/truecase/truecasing.fast.caseless.qn.ser.gz
>  mixedCaseMapFile=edu/stanford/nlp/models/truecase/MixDisambiguation.list
> classBias=INIT_UPPER:-0.7,UPPER:-0.7,O:0
> Exception in thread "main" edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to open "edu/stanford/nlp/models/truecase/truecasing.fast.caseless.qn.ser.gz" as class path, filename or URL
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.ie.AbstractSequenceClassifier.loadClassifierNoExceptions(AbstractSequenceClassifier.java:1499)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.TrueCaseAnnotator.(TrueCaseAnnotator.java:58)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorImplementations.trueCase(AnnotatorImplementations.java:199)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorFactories$10.create(AnnotatorFactories.java:435)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.AnnotatorPool.get(AnnotatorPool.java:85)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.construct(StanfordCoreNLP.java:375)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:139)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.(StanfordCoreNLP.java:135)
>     at edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP.main(StanfordCoreNLP.java:1222)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried to make the default models jar a bit smaller and decided to not include this model by default. But it is still contained in the English models jar which you can download from [release history](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/history.html) page.

After you downloaded the jar, make sure to put it in your classpath before you run CoreNLP. The English models jar should also contain everything in `stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar`, so you won't need both of them in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Any idea how to get the corrected case for an input sentence using the command line and use that in subsequent annotators? For example running "java -Xmx4g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP -annotators tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,truecase,ner,parse -file test.txt -outputFormat conll" with a sentence like "This is a test sentence I'd LIKE to parse.
" doesn't give the expected "LIKE" = like. Obviously I'm missing something here...

Comment: @Sebastian Schuster, any idea how to add the English model to maven in pom.xml? Just plugging into a new code base here and new to maven.